# Decision tree for binary classification

Tags: python, design-patterns, python-3.x, tree

I want to become a good Python programmer and so I'd like to know what in my code practices I can improve. Overall I feel like a pretty solid programmer but writing this code felt very "Java" so I am probably still following poor practices in terms of following Python code practices.

```
__author__ = "arthur"

import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)

def indices_next(ls):
    indices = []
    for i, element in enumerate(ls):
        if i != 0:
            if element != ls[i-1]:
                indices.append(i)
    return indices

def summed_list(ls):
    for i, elt in enumerate(ls):
        if i != 0:
            ls[i] += ls[i-1]
    return ls

class TreeNode(object):
    class_counter = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = TreeNode.class_counter
        TreeNode.class_counter += 1
        self.split_gini = -1000
        self.data = pd.DataFrame()
        self.node_type = "Node"
        self.node_gini = 1.0
        self.split_value = -1000
        self.split_attribute = ""
        self.parent = None
        self.left_child_node = None
        self.left_child_complete = False
        self.split_dict = dict()

        self.right_child_node = None
        self.right_child_complete = False
        self.level = 0

    def compute_gini_new_node(self):
        split_dict = self.data["OK"].value_counts().to_dict()
        self.split_dict = split_dict
        if len(split_dict) == 2:
            # print "Size of split_dict is 2"
            zero_count = float(split_dict[0])
            one_count = float(split_dict[1])
            gini = 1 - (zero_count/(zero_count+one_count))**2 - (one_count/(zero_count+one_count))**2
            self.node_gini = gini

class DecisionTree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TreeNode()
        self.attributes = []
        self.used_attributes = set()

    def is_leaf_node(self, node):
        result = False
        data_ct = len(node.data)
        if len(node.split_dict) == 1:
            result = True
        elif len(node.split_dict) == 2:
            zeroes = node.split_dict[0]
            ones = node.split_dict[1]
            if zeroes == 0 or ones == 0:
                result = True
            else:
                result = False
            if zeroes == 0 and ones == 0:
                result = False
        else:
            result = False
        return result

    def create(self, filename):
        current_node = self.root
        current_node.data = pd.read_csv(filename)
        self.attributes = current_node.data.columns

    def create_test(self, filename):
        csv = pd.read_csv(filename)
        current_node = self.root
        current_node.data = csv[:int((0.8*len(csv)))]
        self.attributes = current_node.data.columns

        testing_data = csv[int((0.8*len(csv))):]

        self.train_tree()

        for i in range(400, 400+len(testing_data)):
            current_node = self.root
            record = testing_data.loc[i]
            while current_node.left_child_node is not None and current_node.right_child_node is not None:
                attr = current_node.split_attribute
                if current_node.split_value <= record[attr]:
                    current_node = current_node.right_child_node
                    continue
                else:
                    current_node = current_node.left_child_node
                    continue
            if len(current_node.split_dict) == 2:
                zero = current_node.split_dict[0]
                #print current_node.split_dict
                one = current_node.split_dict[1]
                zeropc = zero/(float(zero + one))

                onepc = one/(float(zero + one))
                if max(zeropc, onepc) == zeropc:
                    print str(record['ID']) + " is a 0 " + str(zeropc)
                else:
                    print str(record['ID']) + " is a 1 " + str(onepc)


    def train_tree(self):
        self.train_tree_hidden(self.root)

    def get_attribute_ginis(self, current_node):
        attribute_ginis = dict()
        hold_ginis = []
        for attribute in self.attributes[1:10]:
            if attribute not in self.used_attributes:
                # print self.used_attributes
                attribute_ginis[attribute] = []
                # hold_ginis will hold the gini coefficients of every possible splitting condition to find the best one
                # attribute_df uses built in pandas functions to sort by attribute, THEN by ID
                attribute_df = current_node.data.sort([attribute,"ID"])

                # attribute_vals are the actual sorted values of the individual attribute
                attribute_vals = attribute_df[attribute]

                # buckets is a histogram of the different attribute value counts.
                buckets = attribute_vals.value_counts()

                #print attribute

                # since attribute_vals is sorted, we can use this to know the offset
                series = buckets.sort_index()

                # series_keys = series.keys().tolist()
                # for key in series_keys:
                #     offset = series[key]
                #     print str(key) + " " + str(offset)

                summedlist = summed_list(series.tolist())
                #print summedlist
                #return
                count = 0
                for element in summedlist:

                    # we get the sorted list of attribute values, and using elt, the summed indices, we grab the
                    # data that's been sectioned up (see attribute_vals, buckets, etc)
                    subsection = attribute_df[:element]
                    # last_val = subsection[-1:]

                    # this is a series
                    val_counts = subsection["OK"].value_counts()
                    series_size = val_counts.size
                    if series_size == 2:
                        # then we know this node will split and it is not a leaf node
                        left = val_counts[0]
                        right = val_counts[1]
                        if left != 0 or right != 0:
                            gini = 1 - (float(left)/(left+right))**2 - (float(right)/(left+right))**2

                            # hold_ginis.append(tpl)
                    elif series_size == 1:
                        if len(subsection) > 0:
                            gini = 0
                    tpl = (gini, count, element, attribute)
                    attribute_ginis[attribute].append(tpl)
                    count += 1
        return attribute_ginis


    def split(self, current_node):
        attributes_start = current_node.data.columns[1:10]

        attribute_ginis = self.get_attribute_ginis(current_node)

        # print attribute_ginis
        tuple_dict = dict()
        slimmer_ginis = []
        for attribute in attributes_start:
            tuple_dict[attribute] = []
            if attribute not in self.used_attributes:
                # print attribute_ginis
                tuple_list = sorted(attribute_ginis[attribute],  key=lambda x: x[0])
                if len(tuple_list) > 0:
                    slimmer_ginis.append(tuple_list[0])
                    # No, the first tuple is not necessarily the best.
                    # first_tuple_is_best = sorted(slimmer_ginis, key= lambda x: x[0])
                for tpl in tuple_list:
                    if tpl[2] != 500:
                        left_df = current_node.data.sort([attribute,"ID"])[:tpl[2]]
                        right_df = current_node.data.sort([attribute,"ID"])[tpl[2]:]
                        #print "first half"
                        #left_freq = left_df[attribute].value_counts()
                        #print "second half"

                        # right_freq = right_df[attribute].value_counts()

                        left_freq = left_df["OK"].value_counts()

                        right_freq = right_df["OK"].value_counts()
                        leftsum = 0
                        rightsum = 0
                        if len(left_freq) == 0:
                            left_gini = 0
                        elif len(left_freq) == 1:
                            left_gini = 0
                        else:

                            left_gini = 1 - (left_freq[0]/float(left_freq[0] + left_freq[1]))**2 - (left_freq[1]/float(left_freq[0] + left_freq[1]))**2
                            leftsum = left_freq[0] + left_freq[1]

                        #print "LG " + str(left_gini)

                        if len(right_freq) == 0:
                            right_gini = 0
                        elif len(right_freq) == 1:
                            right_gini = 0
                        else:
                            right_gini = 1 - (right_freq[0]/float(right_freq[0] + right_freq[1]))**2 - (right_freq[1]/float(right_freq[0] + right_freq[1]))**2
                            rightsum = right_freq[0] + right_freq[1]

                        #print "RG " + str(right_gini)
                        if left_gini == 0 or right_gini == 0:
                            continue
                        else:

                            split_gini = left_gini*(leftsum/float(leftsum+rightsum)) + right_gini*(rightsum/float(leftsum+rightsum))
                            #print "SG " + str(split_gini)
                            info_gain = current_node.node_gini - split_gini
                            #print info_gain

                            tuple_dict[attribute].append((tpl[0], tpl[1], tpl[2], attribute, left_gini, right_gini, split_gini, info_gain))
                        # print tuple_dict
        total_list = []
        #print tuple_dict
        for key in tuple_dict.keys():
            for val in tuple_dict[key]:
                total_list.append(val)
        list = sorted(total_list,  key=lambda x: x[7])

        if len(list) == 0:
            return

        x = list[0]

        gini = x[0]
        valsplit = x[1]
        ind = x[2]

        attribute_to_split_on = x
        # smallest_gini_value_tuple = start_tuple[0]
        current_node.node_gini = gini
        best_attribute_to_split_on_based_on_gini = x[3]
        best_attribute = best_attribute_to_split_on_based_on_gini
        attribute_df = current_node.data.sort([best_attribute,"ID"])
        # print len(attribute_df)


        current_node.split_value = x[1]
        # attribute_df[:ind][-1:][best_attribute].tolist()[0]


        current_node.split_attribute = best_attribute

        current_node.left_child_node = TreeNode()
        current_node.left_child_node.parent = current_node

        current_node.right_child_node = TreeNode()
        current_node.right_child_node.parent = current_node

        current_node.left_child_node.data = attribute_df[:ind]
        current_node.right_child_node.data = attribute_df[ind:]

        # print best_attribute
        # print "left node data count " + str(len(current_node.left_child_node.data))
        # print "LEFT NODE DATA BEGINS"
        # print "--------------"
        # #print current_node.left_child_node.data
        # print "--------------"
        # print "LEFT NODE DATA ENDS"

        lnode_data = current_node.left_child_node.data
        #
        # print "right node data count " + str(len(current_node.right_child_node.data))
        # print "RIGHT NODE DATA BEGINS"
        # print "--------------"
        # #print current_node.right_child_node.data
        # print "--------------"
        # print "RIGHT NODE DATA ENDS"
        rnode_data = current_node.right_child_node.data

        current_node.left_child_node.compute_gini_new_node()
        current_node.right_child_node.compute_gini_new_node()

        left_half_split_gini = (float(len(lnode_data))/len(current_node.data))*current_node.left_child_node.node_gini
        right_half_split_gini = (float(len(rnode_data))/len(current_node.data))*current_node.right_child_node.node_gini

        current_node.split_gini = left_half_split_gini + right_half_split_gini

        # print "Split gini " + str(current_node.split_gini)
        # print current_node.split_attribute
        # print "I am " + str(current_node.name)
        # if current_node.parent is not None:
        #   print "My parent is " + str(current_node.parent.name)
        # print "LTE " + str(current_node.split_value)
        # print "left is " + str(current_node.left_child_node.data["OK"].value_counts().to_dict())
        # print "right is " + str(current_node.right_child_node.data["OK"].value_counts().to_dict())
        #
        #
        # left_gini = current_node.left_child_node.node_gini
        # right_gini = current_node.right_child_node.node_gini
        #
        # print "left gini is " + str(left_gini)
        #
        # print "right gini is " + str(right_gini)
        # print ""

        self.used_attributes.add(x[3])

    def train_tree_hidden(self, current_node):
        not_done = True

        while not_done:
            self.split(current_node)

            if current_node.left_child_node is None and current_node.right_child_node is None:
                print "Current node is a leaf node!!!"
                return
            else:
                left_gini = current_node.left_child_node.node_gini
                right_gini = current_node.right_child_node.node_gini
                split_gini = current_node.split_gini
                # print "do i get here"
                left_gain = (left_gini - split_gini)
                right_gain = (right_gini - split_gini)

                if max(left_gain, right_gain) == left_gain:
                    current_node = current_node.left_child_node
                else:
                    current_node = current_node.right_child_node
                continue



    def test(self, filename):
        current_node = self.root

        csv = pd.read_csv(filename)
        freq = dict()
        freq[0] = 0
        freq[1] = 0
        print "ID,OK"
        for i in range(0, len(csv)):
            current_node = self.root
            record = csv.loc[i]
            while current_node.left_child_node is not None and current_node.right_child_node is not None:
                attr = current_node.split_attribute
                if current_node.split_value <= record[attr]:
                    current_node = current_node.right_child_node
                    continue
                else:
                    current_node = current_node.left_child_node
                    continue
            if len(current_node.split_dict) == 2:
                zero = current_node.split_dict[0]
                # print current_node.split_dict
                one = current_node.split_dict[1]
                zeropc = zero/(float(zero + one))

                onepc = one/(float(zero + one))
                if max(zeropc, onepc) == zeropc:
                    print str(record['ID'])+",0"
                    freq[0] += 1
                else:
                    print str(record['ID']) + ",1" # + str(onepc)
                    freq[1] += 1
        #print freq






        # print csv

def main(filename):
    filename = "training.csv"

    dt = DecisionTree()
    dt.create(filename)
    dt.train_tree()
    dt.test("test.csv")

    # dt.create_test(filename)




# dt.test("test.csv")

main("training.csv")
```

Answer (score 3):

***Disclaimer** I'm less concerned about how Pythonic the code is than how understandable it is.*

### A Few Observations

1. There are almost 400 lines of code. It is not easy to see how it all fits together.
2. There are comments. None of them paint the big picture. Many comments are just dead code. These impede clarity.
3. Tests are mixed in with production code. This adds to bulk and makes the main logic more difficult to understand not less.

### A Few Suggestions

1. Make the code more modular by removing tests from the production logic.
2. Delete dead code. Consider using version control to maintain historical investigations instead.
3. Consider writing an overall description of the program, so that anyone reading it, including yourself a week from now, can more quickly understand what the code does and how it hangs together to do it.
4. Consider better names.

   - What does `tuple_dict` represent, i.e. what are the these tuples of?
   - `zero` might be better labelled as `zero_coefficient` unless it is `0`.
   - Why`TreeNode` instead of `Node`? The rest of the program uses *node* to refer to nodes.
5. Why does `TreeNode` contain so many magic numbers? Perhaps this should be passed as a parameter from a file?